# Python Lambda function succeeds but no rows appear updated

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, psycopg2

I have an AWS lamda function making an update to my RDS.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    connection = psycopg2.connect(user="****", password=****,
                                  host=****, port="****",
                                  database="****")
    
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    postgres_put_query = "UPDATE restaurant SET (item, price) = ('{0}','{1}') WHERE id = '{2}'".format(event['item'], event['price'], event['id'])
    cursor.execute(postgres_put_query)
    print(cursor.rowcount)
```

The print statement prints `1` as expected however when I look at the data in my database no updates were made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to call `connection.commit()` to reflect the change in database

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    connection = psycopg2.connect(user="****", password=****,
                                  host=****, port="****",
                                  database="****")
    
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    postgres_put_query = "UPDATE restaurant SET (item, price) = ('{0}','{1}') WHERE id = '{2}'".format(event['item'], event['price'], event['id'])
    cursor.execute(postgres_put_query)
    print(cursor.rowcount)
    connection.commit()
```

Comment: I get the following error: "errorMessage": "'psycopg2.extensions.cursor' object has no attribute 'commit'"